# JsTree - Expand by clicking Parent Node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using JsTree.  Right now, the elements of the tree only expand when the icon NEXT to the parent node is clicked.  How can I make it so the tree expands also when the parent node is clicked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The full list of commands can be found here:http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core
Below is a rough implementation of the close_node and open_node listening to the click event.

```
.jstree({...}).delegate(".jstree-open>a", "click.jstree", function(event){
    $.jstree._reference(this).close_node(this,false,false);
}).delegate(".jstree-closed>a", "click.jstree", function(event){
    $.jstree._reference(this).open_node(this,false,false);
});
```

Comment: How can I find state of a clicked node ? I am binding jstree (using JSON data ) using .bind("select_node.jstree",function(event, data){..}. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excellent answer, tested and works great for me too.

Comment: Note: New jsTree uses ".reference" and not "._reference" :) confused me for a min

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Cammy , the above code was for the 1.0beta release